# Docker Compose - Run java web application (war file) on tomcat using volumes

Tags: tomcat, docker, docker-compose, war, volumes

I try to deploy a java web application using maven and tomcat on docker. I am using two Dockerfiles, one for my maven project and one for tomcat composing them with docker-compose and then i copy the .war file from the maven container to the tomcat container but with a way i dont really like. Im sure that there is a way to do it with volumes and thats my question. My files are these...

maven Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8

RUN git clone mygitproject

# Create app directory
WORKDIR mics-project

RUN mvn install
```

tomcat Dockerfile_tc

```
FROM tomcat:8.0-jre8

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/bin

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    maven:
        container_name: maven-container
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile

    tomcat:
        container_name: tomcat-container
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile_tc
        ports:
           - "8080:8080"
```

And then i have a .bat file and im running some commands to copy my war file to tomcat...

```
cd C:\Users\Administrator\Project\mics-project

del "mics-project.war" >nul 2>&1

start docker cp maven-container:/mics-project/target/mics-project.war c:/Users/Administrator/Project/mics-project

start docker cp c:/Users/Administrator/Project/mics-project/mics-project.war tomcat-container:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

It works! But how can i use volumes in my docker-compose.yml file instead of executing these commands?

Answer (score 0):

you can use volumes directly in YAML files

```
volumes:
  - Path_on_local_pc:Path_on_container
```

this block will be under tomcat and parallel to build and ports

```
tomcat:
    container_name: tomcat-container
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile_tc
    ports:
       - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
       - Path_on_local_pc:Path_on_container
```

You can add likewise.

Reference for the same - https://www.linux.com/learn/docker-volumes-and-networks-compose

Comment: Hi and thank you for the answer! Im downloading my code direct from git to the maven container. I dont have the code or the .war file local. What is the Path_on_local_pc in my case?

Comment: File you want to copy to container. It will be path for that file

Comment: But the file i want to copy is in the other container. The war file is in maven container and i want to copy this file to the tomcat container. Maybe i need two volumes?

Comment: There is one hack to do this. I don`t know if this will work in your case or not. First mount the path of container A from where you want to copy to host computer. By this, Data will come to your system. And later mount the same directory to container B.

Comment: Thats that im trying to do. But it doesnt work. Can you give me a simple yml file example? Im working on linux host and guest...

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer could be late but it might help others.If it it contains a pom.xml file. Then you can create a single docker file to build the image. Without having to execute other commands

> FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8 AS buildserver
>
> WORKDIR /usr/mygitproject

git clone into container path

> RUN git clone mygitproject /usr/mygitproject
>
> WORKDIR /usr/mygitproject /src

build the project

> RUN mvn -f /usr/mygitproject /pom.xml clean package -DskipTests
>
> FROM tomcat:latest

Copy the built war file into webapps folder of tomcat container

> COPY --from=buildserver /usr/mygitproject /target/*.war
> /usr/local/tomcat/webapps